# VSCode automatically scrolling to right without input

Tags: scrolling, visual-studio-code

VSCode is constantly scrolling to the right. Disable all but one Mouse and KB. Tried multiple configurations, still auto scrolling to the right.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with hardware. An out-of-sight input device was enabled and sending side scrolling cursor movement.

Sorry for the anti-climax years later.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score -1):

Check the VS Code 'Settings' and click on 'Text Editor' in the left colon
One of the settings you should see now is the one you need to change. (but I don't know which one exactly)

Comment: This answer is too vague and not helpful. I have already tried searching in the VS Code settings (including the `Text Editor` section) and cannot find anything that will fix this.